# How to set width of bar graph in units of axis

Tags: tikz-pgf

I want to plot the following data as a bar graph, where the width of each bar is 784.7913898303067 in units of the axis:

```
-8907.243859923638 2.178160631669683e-06
-8122.452470093331 8.712642526678732e-06
-7337.661080263024 4.356321263339366e-06
-6552.869690432717 1.0890803158348416e-05
-5768.07830060241 1.7425285053357465e-05
-4983.2869107721035 1.9603445685027148e-05
-4198.495520941797 3.9206891370054296e-05
-3413.70413111149 6.752297958176017e-05
-2628.912741281183 0.00012415515600517195
-1844.1213514508763 0.00015900572611188686
-1059.3299616205695 0.00018949997495526245
-274.53857179026284 0.00020039077811361084
510.25281804004385 0.00016989652927023528
1295.0442078703504 0.00011326435284682353
2079.835597700657 7.62356221084389e-05
2864.626987530964 3.267240947504525e-05
3649.418377361271 1.5247124421687783e-05
4434.209767191577 4.356321263339366e-06
5219.001157021884 4.356321263339366e-06
6003.792546852191 1.0890803158348416e-05
6788.583936682498 0.0
7573.375326512804 4.356321263339366e-06
8358.16671634311 0.0
9142.958106173417 0.0
```

I am doing:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}
        [
        width=\linewidth,
        title = {Late Speed Distribution},
        xlabel = {$v$~[m/s]},
        ylabel = {Probability Density},
        ]
        \addplot[ybar, white!45!blue, fill = white!45!blue,bar width=784.7913898303067] table {barSpeeds.txt};
        \addplot[thick, red, domain=-10500:10500, samples=100]  {0.00016312130913239263 * exp(-8.359326130920716e-08*x*x)} node[black, pos = 0, anchor=south west]{$P(v_x) = \sqrt{\frac{m}{2\pi K_B T}}\exp\left(-\frac{1}{2}\frac{mv_x^2}{K_BT}\right)$};
        \end{axis}
```

But, I guess, that the bar width parameter works in some other units.
I have managed to get it to work by using `\pgfplotsset{compat=1.8}` before the axis environment, but for some other reason this shifts my entire figure downwards and it ends up misaligned with respect to another figure I have next to this one.

**EDIT:**
Using `\pgfplotsset{compat=1.8}` partially solves the problem. It allows me to set the width in units of the axis. But for some reason (why?) it shifts the position of my image, and it is no longer aligned.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[top=2.54cm, bottom=2.54cm, left=2.75cm, right=2.75cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{filecontents*}{barSpeeds2.txt}
    -8907.243859923638 2.178160631669683e-06
    -8122.452470093331 8.712642526678732e-06
    -7337.661080263024 4.356321263339366e-06
    -6552.869690432717 1.0890803158348416e-05
    -5768.07830060241 1.7425285053357465e-05
    -4983.2869107721035 1.9603445685027148e-05
    -4198.495520941797 3.9206891370054296e-05
    -3413.70413111149 6.752297958176017e-05
    -2628.912741281183 0.00012415515600517195
    -1844.1213514508763 0.00015900572611188686
    -1059.3299616205695 0.00018949997495526245
    -274.53857179026284 0.00020039077811361084
    510.25281804004385 0.00016989652927023528
    1295.0442078703504 0.00011326435284682353
    2079.835597700657 7.62356221084389e-05
    2864.626987530964 3.267240947504525e-05
    3649.418377361271 1.5247124421687783e-05
    4434.209767191577 4.356321263339366e-06
    5219.001157021884 4.356321263339366e-06
    6003.792546852191 1.0890803158348416e-05
    6788.583936682498 0.0
    7573.375326512804 4.356321263339366e-06
    8358.16671634311 0.0
    9142.958106173417 0.0
\end{filecontents*}
\begin{filecontents*}{radialT2.txt}
    x   y   z
    0   724.6251253 27.23673321
    0.00011625  519.0500608 21.50619688
    0.0002325   471.8535621 20.0953379
    0.00034875  458.3159477 20.51917732
    0.000465    378.1946348 15.32643944
    0.00058125  402.6761363 16.59979084
    0.0006975   330.7735982 12.35631702
    0.00081375  483.4846951 17.4573978
    0.00093 879.0654654 17.75191929
\end{filecontents*}
\begin{document} 
    \begin{figure}[H]
        \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.49\textwidth}
            \centering
            \begin{tikzpicture}
            \pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
            \begin{axis}
            [
            width=\linewidth,
            title = {Late Speed Distribution},
            xlabel = {$v$~[m/s]},
            ylabel = {Probability Density},
            ]
            \addplot[ybar, white!45!blue, fill = white!45!blue,bar width=784.7913898303067] table {barSpeeds2.txt};
            \addplot[thick, red, domain=-10500:10500, samples=100]  {0.00016312130913239263 * exp(-8.359326130920716e-08*x*x)} node[black, pos = 1, anchor=south west]{$P(v_x) = \sqrt{\frac{m}{2\pi K_B T}}\exp\left(-\frac{1}{2}\frac{mv_x^2}{K_BT}\right)$};
            \end{axis}
            \end{tikzpicture}
            \label{fig:tempProbab}
        \end{subfigure}
        \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.49\textwidth}
            \centering
            \begin{tikzpicture}
            \begin{axis}
            [
            width=\linewidth,
            title = {Temperature Radial Distribution},
            xlabel = $r~\text{[m]}$,
            ylabel = {Temperature~[K]},
            ]
            \addplot [blue,dashed,thick]
            plot [error bars/.cd, y dir = both, y explicit]
            table[y error index=2]{radialT2.txt};
            \end{axis}
            \end{tikzpicture}
            \label{fig:radialTemp}
        \end{subfigure}
        \caption{(a) . (b) .}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

This is how it currently looks like: And is there any way to set the equation automatically in the plot somewhere where it doesn't overlap with the graph?

Thanks
[image: Graph]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I may not understand the question, but once I complete your fragments to a document I get what I think is the desired result with version `1.17` (`1.15` and `1.16` yield the same result, other versions I did not test).

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{filecontents*}{barSpeeds.txt}
-8907.243859923638 2.178160631669683e-06
-8122.452470093331 8.712642526678732e-06
-7337.661080263024 4.356321263339366e-06
-6552.869690432717 1.0890803158348416e-05
-5768.07830060241 1.7425285053357465e-05
-4983.2869107721035 1.9603445685027148e-05
-4198.495520941797 3.9206891370054296e-05
-3413.70413111149 6.752297958176017e-05
-2628.912741281183 0.00012415515600517195
-1844.1213514508763 0.00015900572611188686
-1059.3299616205695 0.00018949997495526245
-274.53857179026284 0.00020039077811361084
510.25281804004385 0.00016989652927023528
1295.0442078703504 0.00011326435284682353
2079.835597700657 7.62356221084389e-05
2864.626987530964 3.267240947504525e-05
3649.418377361271 1.5247124421687783e-05
4434.209767191577 4.356321263339366e-06
5219.001157021884 4.356321263339366e-06
6003.792546852191 1.0890803158348416e-05
6788.583936682498 0.0
7573.375326512804 4.356321263339366e-06
8358.16671634311 0.0
9142.958106173417 0.0
\end{filecontents*}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.17}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}
        [
        width=0.9\linewidth,
        title = {Late Speed Distribution},
        xlabel = {$v$~[m/s]},
        ylabel = {Probability Density},
        ]
        \addplot[ybar, white!45!blue, fill = white!45!blue,bar width=784.7913898303067] table {barSpeeds.txt};
        \addplot[thick, red, domain=-10500:10500, samples=100]  {0.00016312130913239263 * exp(-8.359326130920716e-08*x*x)} node[black, pos = 0, anchor=south west]{$P(v_x) = \sqrt{\frac{m}{2\pi K_B T}}\exp\left(-\frac{1}{2}\frac{mv_x^2}{K_BT}\right)$};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

In case this does not answer the question, it may at least help defining it.

As for the updated question: the main problem disappears once you add subfigure captions, which you should IMHO anyway. As for the visibility of the formula: there is to the best of my knowledge no magical trick. I added two ad hoc possibilities: `contour` and increasing `ymax`.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[top=2.54cm, bottom=2.54cm, left=2.75cm, right=2.75cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.17}
\usepackage[outline]{contour}
\contourlength{0.6pt}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{filecontents*}{barSpeeds2.txt}
    -8907.243859923638 2.178160631669683e-06
    -8122.452470093331 8.712642526678732e-06
    -7337.661080263024 4.356321263339366e-06
    -6552.869690432717 1.0890803158348416e-05
    -5768.07830060241 1.7425285053357465e-05
    -4983.2869107721035 1.9603445685027148e-05
    -4198.495520941797 3.9206891370054296e-05
    -3413.70413111149 6.752297958176017e-05
    -2628.912741281183 0.00012415515600517195
    -1844.1213514508763 0.00015900572611188686
    -1059.3299616205695 0.00018949997495526245
    -274.53857179026284 0.00020039077811361084
    510.25281804004385 0.00016989652927023528
    1295.0442078703504 0.00011326435284682353
    2079.835597700657 7.62356221084389e-05
    2864.626987530964 3.267240947504525e-05
    3649.418377361271 1.5247124421687783e-05
    4434.209767191577 4.356321263339366e-06
    5219.001157021884 4.356321263339366e-06
    6003.792546852191 1.0890803158348416e-05
    6788.583936682498 0.0
    7573.375326512804 4.356321263339366e-06
    8358.16671634311 0.0
    9142.958106173417 0.0
\end{filecontents*}
\begin{filecontents*}{radialT2.txt}
    x   y   z
    0   724.6251253 27.23673321
    0.00011625  519.0500608 21.50619688
    0.0002325   471.8535621 20.0953379
    0.00034875  458.3159477 20.51917732
    0.000465    378.1946348 15.32643944
    0.00058125  402.6761363 16.59979084
    0.0006975   330.7735982 12.35631702
    0.00081375  483.4846951 17.4573978
    0.00093 879.0654654 17.75191929
\end{filecontents*}
\begin{document} 
    \begin{figure}[H]
        \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.49\textwidth}
            \centering
            \begin{tikzpicture}
            \pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
            \begin{axis}
            [
            width=\linewidth,
            title = {Late Speed Distribution},
            xlabel = {$v$~[m/s]},
            ylabel = {Probability Density},
            ]
            \addplot[ybar, white!45!blue, fill = white!45!blue,bar width=784.7913898303067] table {barSpeeds2.txt};
            \addplot[thick, red, domain=-10500:10500, samples=100]  
            {0.00016312130913239263 * exp(-8.359326130920716e-08*x*x)} 
            node[black, pos = 0.5, anchor=south]{\contour{white}{$P(v_x) =
            \sqrt{\frac{m}{2\pi\, k_\mathrm{B}\,
            T}}\exp\left(-\frac{1}{2}\frac{m\,v_x^2}{k_\mathrm{B}\,T}\right)$}};
            \end{axis}
            \end{tikzpicture}
            \caption{}
           \label{fig:tempProbab-2}
        \end{subfigure}
        \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.49\textwidth}
            \centering
            \begin{tikzpicture}
            \begin{axis}
            [
            width=\linewidth,
            title = {Temperature Radial Distribution},
            xlabel = $r~\text{[m]}$,
            ylabel = {Temperature~[K]},
            ]
            \addplot [blue,dashed,thick]
            plot [error bars/.cd, y dir = both, y explicit]
            table[y error index=2]{radialT2.txt};
            \end{axis}
            \end{tikzpicture}
            \caption{}
            \label{fig:radialTemp-2}
        \end{subfigure}
        \caption{Using \texttt{contour}.}
    \end{figure}

    \begin{figure}[h]
        \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.49\textwidth}
            \centering
            \begin{tikzpicture}
            \pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
            \begin{axis}
            [
            width=\linewidth,
            title = {Late Speed Distribution},
            xlabel = {$v$~[m/s]},
            ylabel = {Probability Density},
            ymax=2.6e-4
            ]
            \addplot[ybar, white!45!blue, fill = white!45!blue,bar width=784.7913898303067] table {barSpeeds2.txt};
            \addplot[thick, red, domain=-10500:10500, samples=100]  
            {0.00016312130913239263 * exp(-8.359326130920716e-08*x*x)} 
            node[black, pos = 0.5, anchor=south,yshift=5mm]{$P(v_x) =
            \sqrt{\frac{m}{2\pi\, k_\mathrm{B}\,
            T}}\exp\left(-\frac{1}{2}\frac{m\,v_x^2}{k_\mathrm{B}\,T}\right)$};
            \end{axis}
            \end{tikzpicture}
            \caption{}
           \label{fig:tempProbab}
        \end{subfigure}
        \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.49\textwidth}
            \centering
            \begin{tikzpicture}
            \begin{axis}
            [
            width=\linewidth,
            title = {Temperature Radial Distribution},
            xlabel = $r~\text{[m]}$,
            ylabel = {Temperature~[K]},
            ]
            \addplot [blue,dashed,thick]
            plot [error bars/.cd, y dir = both, y explicit]
            table[y error index=2]{radialT2.txt};
            \end{axis}
            \end{tikzpicture}
            \caption{}
            \label{fig:radialTemp}
        \end{subfigure}
        \caption{Increasing \texttt{ymax} and shifting the node.}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hi, sorry for my sloppy description of the complete problem. Can you have a look at my edit please? Thanks

Comment: @DanielDuque It is still a fragment. Please provide some code which starts with `\documentclass`, ends with `\end{document}`, and can be compiled. This is particularly important here since the `subfigure` environment gets defined in at least two packages, and it is too cumbersome to find out which one you are using. (If you are using the `subfigure` package, that one is deprecated, use `subcaption` instead.)

Comment: Thanks, I have updated my question and included the packages I am using.

Comment: @DanielDuque I added some possibilities.